# How do I get Windows to allow me to use drivers that don't have a valid signature?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

[image]

The strange part is, a few months ago, this would application work fine without any issue. Now I get this error.

Comment: Was it possibly Win 7 SP1 that changed this?

Comment: It is possible the driver was signed but not timestamped. If you do that, the driver will be considered unsigned as soon as the signing key expires. Contact the driver supplier for a valid driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'd contact the application developer and make sure this is a legit mistake.  Drivers that are all the sudden untrusted are a dead giveaway for malware, specifically rootkits.

If it is a legit mistake, you can reboot and hit F8 while Windows is loading up.  There is an option to disable the Integrity Check that will then allow installs of unsigned drivers.

Comment: I would not suggest turning off Integrity Check.  Contact the author of the driver and request a signed driver.

Comment: @Ramhound: You are just repeating the first part of my answer. . .

Comment: … whilst you in turn are not reading the first part of xyr comment.  ☺

Comment: @JdeBP: Which I did? F8 + disable is a one time affair. My answer says, contact dev.  His is contact dev. Maybe my English is off. . .

Comment: No you clearly didn't if that's what you think xyr comment is.  Read it again, starting from *the first part*.

Comment: @JdeBP:You need to read my first part . . .

Comment: Now you're just being silly.

Comment: I know. I thought I could reason with you.